# Nodemailor can't sending emails on cross domains

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer, email

I am using nodemailor for sending emails with node and express application.

issues : when i am sending emails on  cross domain for ex : i am using hostgator email server it was sending email on hosted emails only with hostgator , but while i am sending emails on Gmail it will return success

```
250 OK id=1hU5l2-000m0C-Lh
```

but not getting emails.

Note : getting success response but not receiving emails in case of cross domain

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
emailCredentaials = (data) => {

      var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport ({
        host: 'my.hostgator.com',
        port: 465,
        secure:true,
        auth: {
            user: keys.email.emailUserName,
            pass: keys.email.emailPassword
          },
          tls: {
            // do not fail on invalid certs
            rejectUnauthorized: false
          }  
        }));
    var mailOptions = {
        from: keys.email.emailUserName,
        to: data.email,
        subject: 'Demo account credentials',
        html: '<h3>Please Follow the link to login : '
            + keys.emailLinks.accountCredentailLink + '<h3>' + '<br>Useraname &nbsp;&nbsp; : &nbsp;&nbsp;' + data.email + '</br><br> Password &nbsp;&nbsp; : &nbsp;&nbsp;' + data.password + '</br>'
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("***********" + error);
        } else {
            console.log('*********Email sent:********' + info.response);
        }
    });
}
module.exports = emailCredentaials;
```

I used above configuration for nodemailor . Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After digging a lot finally i come back with following answer, if someone having same issue please try with following solution . I added following configuration .

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

emailCredentaials = (data) => {

    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
        name: 'hostgator',
        host: 'my.hostgator.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: keys.email.emailUserName,
            pass: keys.email.emailPassword
        }
    }));

    var mailOptions = {
        from: keys.email.emailUserName,
        to: data.email,
        subject: 'Demo account credentials',
        html: '<h3>Please Follow the link to login : '
            + keys.emailLinks.accountCredentailLink + '<h3>' + '<br>Useraname &nbsp;&nbsp; : &nbsp;&nbsp;' + data.email + '</br><br> Password &nbsp;&nbsp; : &nbsp;&nbsp;' + data.password + '</br>'
    };


    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("***********" + error);
        } else {
            console.log('*********Email sent:********' + info.response);
        }
    });
}
module.exports = emailCredentaials;
```

changes in posted question :

- Needs to add "nodemailer-smtp-transport"

> npm install --save nodemailer-smtp-transport

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
        name: 'hostgator',
        host: 'my.hostgator.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: keys.email.emailUserName,
            pass: keys.email.emailPassword
        }
    }));
```

- above added "**name**" property it's a server name , Thanks

Comment: @LingchaoCao Great , happy coding :)

Comment: I had the same problem but adding the parameter "name" to the createTrasnsport function solved my problem.

Comment: Hi @MiguelAraya great, same posted in answer, you can mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

It saved my week! Thank you so much